# Database insert in order-details page of WooCommerce is not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to do an insert to a MySQL database in WordPress using $wpdb->insert. It is just a simple log, but it is not working.

I am trying to save some basic items from an order I received after a purchase made in WooCommerce. The page to which I added the code is order-details.php and belongs to WooCommerce.

The code:

```
<?php
            do_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table_items', $order );
            $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $creditos =0;
            foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {

                $item_quantity = $item->get_quantity();

                $product = $item->get_product();
                $product_name = $product->get_name();


                if( $product_name == "orián (paquete mínimo)"){
                    $creditos=15;
                }

                if( $product_name == "Andrómeda (paquete medio)"){
                    $creditos=30;
                }

                if( $product_name == "Lira (paquete básico)"){
                    $creditos=50;
                }

                if( $product_name == "Cisne (paquete real + 15 créditos)"){
                    $creditos=65;
                }

                if( $product_name == "Perseo (Paquete Premium + 30 créditos)"){
                    $creditos=120;
                }



               echo $item_quantity." ".$product_name." ".$creditos." ".$fecha." ".get_current_user_id();

                $wpdb->insert( 
                    'registrorden', 
                array( 
                    'idusuario' => get_current_user_id(), 
                    'paquete' => $product_name,
                    'cantidad' => $item_quantity,
                    'creditos' => $creditos

                ), 
                array( 
                    '%d',
                    '%s',
                    '%d',
                    '%d'
                )    
                );




                wc_get_template( 'order/order-details-item.php', array(
                    'order'              => $order,
                    'item_id'            => $item_id,
                    'item'               => $item,
                    'show_purchase_note' => $show_purchase_note,
                    'purchase_note'      => $product ? $product->get_purchase_note() : '',
                    'product'            => $product,
                ) );
            }

            do_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table_items', $order );
            ?>
```

The code I added:

```
$wpdb->insert( 
            'registrorden', 
        array( 
            'idusuario' => get_current_user_id(), 
            'paquete' => $product_name,
            'cantidad' => $item_quantity,
            'creditos' => $creditos

        ), 
        array( 
            '%d',
            '%s',
            '%d',
            '%d'
        )    
        );
```

[Here is a snapshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyMOR.png), and [here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsvUu.png).

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: $wpdb is a var outside of your page/current scope so make sure you bring it in with ```global $wpdb;``` so you have access to use it

Comment: @ray  thank your so much.  it worked.